# Calculate Effective Address Register in z/OS

Tags: zos, addressing-mode, hla

5.5.2.(3)+ Suppose the contents of the general registers are as follows:

```
C(GR0) = 00010A20 C(GR8) = 8031B244

C(GR1) = 42319B7C C(GR9) = 00000010

C(GR2) = 91F0F002 C(GR10) = 723B94C1

C(GR3) = 1002340A C(GR11) = E931AB7F

C(GR4) = 00FF00FF C(GR12) = 00000E38

C(GR5) = D907C401 C(GR13) = 6B005000

C(GR6) = 12345678 C(GR14) = 80000000

C(GR7) = 992B42A3 C(GR15) = FFFFFFFF
```

For each of the following memory addresses, determine first whether or not that memory
location is addressable by a program using those registers. If it is addressable, determine an
addressing halfword (base-displacement halfword) that can be used to address the location.

```
X′ FFFFFF′
```

This question is from Assembler Language Programming for IBM z System Servers
Anyone can explain me about the answer....
the answer on the book is

```
X′ F000′
```

I already get about base and index calculation on using RX instruction. But I can't get this one, thank you if you can explain it to me...

Comment: There's something not clear. Are you saying that the address you are given is X'00FFFFFF' and you don't understand why the base-displacement operand is F000?

Comment: F000 is the answer

Comment: Have you learned about addressing modes yet (AMODE 24/31/64)?

Comment: I did not learn it yet.. the question that i post is still at the basic

Comment: The answer is F000 if the processor is running in 24-bit mode (using only the right three bytes of the register. If the processor is in 31- or 64-bit mode, it is impossible to address X'00FFFFFF' using the standard base-displacement operand and the values given.

Comment: However, using the RXY or RSY format, it is possible to address X'00FFFFFF' using register 4, it would be X'FF00'(4) (although the format in the instruction would be different).

Comment: Ok thank you sir... why you dont add answer. So i can accept it :D